# Sum of column values on individual month

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Timestamp   Consumption
4/1/2017 20:00  257
4/1/2017 21:00  262
4/1/2017 22:00  256
4/1/2017 23:00  256
4/2/2017 0:00   263
4/2/2017 1:00   256
4/2/2017 2:00   265
4/2/2017 3:00   259
4/2/2017 4:00   256
4/2/2017 5:00   260
4/2/2017 6:00   265
4/2/2017 7:00   265
```

I want to do the sum of consumption column of individual months and put it in a list. Like :

[1031,2089]

And to do the sum according to time and irrespective of date. Like 23:00 hrs to 06:00 hrs:

[2080]

How can I achieve this? PLease Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, dayfirst=True)
```

Then [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by months with `sum`:

```
a = df.resample('m', on='Timestamp')['Consumption'].sum().dropna().tolist()
print (a)
[1031, 2089]
```

Another similar solution - added [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
a = df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('m')['Consumption'].sum().dropna().tolist()
print (a)
[1031, 2089]
```

Solution with `groupby`, [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) and `sum`:

```
a = df.set_index('Timestamp')
      .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='m'))['Consumption']
      .sum()
      .dropna()
      .tolist()
print (a)
[1031, 2089]
```

EDIT:

If between dates are filtered in `Timestamp` column use [DatetimeIndex Partial String Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing):

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, dayfirst=True)
date1 = '2017-01-04 23:00'
date2 ='2018-02-04 06:00'
df1 = df.set_index('Timestamp')['Consumption']
a = df1.loc[date1:date2].sum()
print (a)
2080
```

EDIT:

If need [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
print (df)
         Timestamp  Consumption
0   4/1/2017 20:00          257
1   4/1/2017 21:00          262
2   4/1/2017 22:00          256
3   4/1/2017 23:00          256
4    4/2/2017 0:00          263
5    4/2/2017 1:00          256
6    4/2/2017 2:00          265
7    4/2/2017 3:00          259
8    4/2/2017 4:00          256
9    4/2/2017 5:00          260
10   4/2/2018 6:00          265
11   4/2/2018 7:00          265
12  4/3/2017 20:00          256
13  4/3/2017 21:00          263
14   4/3/2017 1:00          256
15   4/4/2017 2:00          265
16   4/4/2017 3:00          259
17   4/4/2017 8:00          256
```

---

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, dayfirst=True)
df1 = df.set_index('Timestamp')['Consumption'].between_time('23:00','6:00')
print (df1)
Timestamp
2017-01-04 23:00:00    256
2017-02-04 00:00:00    263
2017-02-04 01:00:00    256
2017-02-04 02:00:00    265
2017-02-04 03:00:00    259
2017-02-04 04:00:00    256
2017-02-04 05:00:00    260
2018-02-04 06:00:00    265
2017-03-04 01:00:00    256
2017-04-04 02:00:00    265
2017-04-04 03:00:00    259
Name: Consumption, dtype: int64

print (df1.sum())
2860
```

Comment: @jexrael, if i want to do the sum according to time and irrespective of date, like 23:00 hrs to 06:00 hrs?

Comment: Do you think `4/2/2017` and time `23:00 hrs to 06:00 hrs` ?

Comment: I mean 4/1/2017 23:00  to 4/2/2017 06:00

Comment: Are always between dates in column `Timestamp`? Or sometimes not?

Comment: The date can be different but the time is the same. 23:00 to 06:00 hrs. I just gave the date for your understanding.

Comment: I add new data sample,  is it what you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139218/discussion-between-dheeraj-and-jezrael).